# ACL permissions for write_dynamic_frame_from_options in to S3 using AWS Glue

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, pyspark, aws-glue

How to add -acl permissions on s3 objects while trying to output Glue DynamicFrame using `write_dynamic_frame_from_options`. I gave this line of code when i tried converting data and drop the csv files into another AWS account S3 bucket

```py
glueContext.write_dynamic_frame.from_options(frame = DATA_temp, connection_type = "s3", connection_options = {"path": "s3://{BUCKETNAME}/{FOLDER1}/#0001"}, format = "csv")
```

My process finished successfully but i was unable to download or open files in that account??

Answer (score 8):

This will do the trick

```
glueContext._jsc.hadoopConfiguration().set("fs.s3.canned.acl", "BucketOwnerFullControl")
```

The scala version is as below:

```
glueContext.sparkContext.hadoopConfiguration.set("fs.s3.canned.acl", "BucketOwnerFullControl")
```