# How to make a file saved to S3 with AWS Glue publicly accessible

Tags: python, amazon-s3, aws-glue

I am trying to save files using AWS Glue and make the file publicly accessible.
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58441733/acl-permissions-for-write-dynamic-frame-from-options-in-to-s3-using-aws-glue) link shows how to set ACL, but I want to make the file publicly accessible. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Couldn't you simply make your S3 bucket publicly available? (Note: Although this is the easiest option, this is not considered best practice: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/security-best-practices.html#security-best-practices-prevent)
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547046/make-a-bucket-public-in-amazon-s3

Comment: I ended up making my S3 bucket publicly accessible although it is not recommended method.